# Add maven project and its dependencies to my project in Eclipse, best workflow

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven, and this is a general workflow question. I have Eclipse Mars, and have added subclipse and m2e to it. I checked out a Java maven project (for instance `MyLib`), and can run its classes inside Eclipse.

Now I want to create my own project (for instance `MyProject`) that will use `MyLib`'s classes. I right-clicked on `MyProject`/Properties/Projects and added all the subfolders from `MyLib`. However, this does not add `MyLib`'s Maven dependencies to with it. I could manually look for all the jars in the .m2 folder and add them, but this sounds like the wrong workflow to me.

I have taken a look at http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/, but the tool and Eclipse with its plugins and possibilities add quite to the learning-curve.

1. What would be the best workflow to be able to access `MyLib` (with its dependencies) in `MyProject` in Eclipse?
2. Do I have to convert `MyProject` to a maven project (Configure/Convert to Maven Project) and then (somehow) add a `MyLib` reference to pom.xml ? If so, how would the pom.xml have to be modified?
3. If this would be the right way, won't that download `MyLib` all over again?

EDIT: What I tried is to click on the pom.xml of `MyLib`, and create a new Module element in it, which then I called `MyLib-MyProject`. But this still does not add the depenendies of `MyLib`, and of course this would only be a temporary solution, because the same problem would appear again if I need another library via Maven, for example `MyLib2`, that also should be referenced from `MyProject`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add MyLib to the build path of MyProject.

`Right Click Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Projects Tab->Add...`

If you have trouble with dependencies, then you could compile MyLib into a jar, and add it as a library to the other project.

`Right Click Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add JARs...`

(or external jars if it's not in the workspace)

Here is a [crunchify tutorial](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-build-java-project-including-all-dependencies-using-maven-maven-resources-maven-dependency-maven-jar-plugin-tutorial/) on creating a jar from a maven project.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is to use myLib as it was a normal maven project, on the mvn repository.

Of course I don't ask you to upload it on the global public repository, you should take a look at some nice proxy that allows you to have private repositories, like Nexus, Archiva, ...

I recommend you to read about Archiva, it's the easy one.
https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi